# Add the buffer to the existing table and spatial join

Tags: sql, postgresql, geospatial, postgis, spatial-query

I have a spatial database with multiple tables, I have created a buffer for a table with points and wanted to add the buffer to the existing table. And wanted to do a spatial join like using this buffer and another table with points to count the number of points inside each buffer and add it as a new column in the existing buffer table. I cannot figure it out.

```
SELECT ST_Buffer(geom::geography,100) FROM public.operation;
UPDATE operations SET buffer = ST_Buffer(geom::geography,100)::geometry;

FROM "Supermarket" AS pts, "geom" as ST_Buffer
WHERE ST_Contains( the_geom, pts.location)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add a new geometry column with `AddGeometryColumn`..

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('public','operations','buffer',4326,'POLYGON',2);
```

.. and then insert the buffers in the new column with an update

```
UPDATE operations SET buffer = ST_Buffer(geom::geography,100)::geometry;
```

**EDIT 1**: Adding a new column to table ´operations` and filling it with the amount of points from another table that spatially overlap with the new buffers:

```
ALTER TABLE operations ADD COLUMN pts int;

UPDATE operations o 
SET pts = (SELECT count(*) FROM supermarket s
           WHERE ST_Contains(o.buffer,s.geom));
```

**EDIT 2** (See comments):

```
CREATE INDEX idx_operation_geom ON operations USING gist (geom);
CREATE INDEX idx_supermarket_geom ON supermarket USING gist (geom);
```

Comment: @Aravinth this is a totally different question, and we're not encouraged to address multiple issues in a single question, since it can get hard to understand or pretty much useless for other users in the community. After you finish this question, post another one with a few data samples (preferably with a fiddle) and the expected results.

Comment: Oh ok, Really thank you for the clarification about the questioning.

Comment: @Aravinth btw: if you haven't done it already, I strongly suggest you to create a `gist` index in the geometry columns.. otherwise operations with this amount of data takes ages to complete.

Comment: Yes it is taking a lot of time, What do you mean by 'gist' index.

Comment: @Aravinth I just edited my answer. Run it before the update... it will be faster.

Comment: The column is created but all the entries are 0, the count is not added to the column pts

Comment: @Aravinth oh no.. I see now :-D, I used the column `geom` instead of `buffer` :-D Just corrected the answer: `UPDATE operations o 
SET pts = (SELECT count(*) FROM supermarket s
           WHERE ST_Contains(o.buffer,s.geom));`

Comment: Sorry for the late response, this works fine. Thank you for the information.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Happy coding @Aravinth